# Redirect non matching subdomains to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have more or less implemented this railscast to get subdomains:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

It works great but I want the non-matching subdomains to redirect to the root path.

This is the routes.rb part:

```
match '/' => 'menus#show', constraints: { subdomain: /^(?!www$)(.+)$/i }
```

And this is in the menus#show:

```
# GET /menus/1
# GET /menus/1.json
def show
  if !params[:id].nil?
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
  else
    if Shop.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain).nil?
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => I18n.t("misc.not_found")) }
          return
        end
      else
       @menu = Shop.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain).menus.last
    end
  end

  if !@menu.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @menu }
    end
  end
end
```

So I still want to keep the possibility not to use subdomains (therefor the check on params[:id].  Then I check if the subdomain exists, if not I want to redirect.

Currently I'm getting this when trying a non existing domain, so I believe he is still trying to show menu:

```
undefined method `shop' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <h2>Menu <%= @menu.shop.name %></h2>
2: <br>
3: <%= render :partial => 'menu_show' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ApplicaitonController, do something like this:

```
before_filter :redirect_on_bad_subdomain

def redirect_on_bad_subdomain
  unless is_valid_subdomain(request.domain)
    redirect_url = root_url(subdomain: 'www')
    redirect_url += request.fullpath[1..request.fullpath.length]
    redirect_to redirect_url and return false
  end
end

def is_valid_subdomain(subdomain) 
  # validate however you want
end
```

I haven't tested out the exact code, but that should be pretty close.

Comment: Hi Javid, thanks for your answer.  This results in a loop, I edited your answer so it works.  Thanks!